# What are the main factors that define the difference between spoken and written language acquisition?

Tags: language-acquisition, written-language

I am writing an essay and could really do with some help. I am only interested in native language acquisition at this time, there seems to be many sources available on spoken language acquisition but no so many on written.

Comment: I am not sure that the process of learning to write your native language is normally seen as part of acquisition of that language. Usually, by the time people learn to write their native language, they are quite well-versed in that language already. This might explain there are few sources on written native language acquisition. I guess there you have your main difference as well. You learn the language in spoken form, but when you learn to write your native language, you learn writing. The most challenging part in that is the abstraction from speech to characters, not learning the language.

Comment: I have heard anecdotally that deaf people have a hard time learning written English when their native language is a signed language. Few other people would "acquire" a written language in the sense that linguists talk about "language acquisition".

Comment: There's language acquisition, which happens very young and tapers off by puberty; and then there's literacy, which may or may not happen, at any age; and then there's second language acquisition, which can happen at any age, with varying degrees of success; and then there's literacy in a second language, which may be all there is (like Latin), or may be learned before or after learning to speak the language. English speakers learn to understand spoken Mandarin long before they learn to read or write it, but with Indonesian literacy and second language learning are almost always simultaneous.